# How to modify a value before saving in EasyAdmin 3

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

Using Symfony 5 and EasyAdmin 3.

I'm using a EasyAdmin `DatetimeField` to show a `Entity->integer` timestamp field.

I've been looking at the docs (https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/fields.html) but can't find anything describing data mutations before storing a value using a callback or something.

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: You should take a look at events section : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/events.html

Comment: Ah of course, I'l take a look..thanks!